# MVC/PDO : how to build a model using PDO's prepared statements syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I want to build a model class for my PHP application. It will have methods meant to select/update/insert/delete specific data from a database according to the method's parameters. I only want to use prepared statements.

Here is an overview of what the class should look like :

```
class Database {

    private $_db;

    // Stores a PDO object (the connection with the database) within the $_db property
    public function __construct($host, $user, $password) {...}

    public function select() {...}

    public function update() {...}

    public function insert() {...}

    public function delete() {...}

}
```

The problem is that I don't really know how to do this. Let's say I want to select everything from the table "farm" where the animal is a dog. The syntax for this statement would be the following :

```
$animal = 'dog';
$query = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = :animal');
$query->execute(array(':animal' => $animal));

$result_set = $query->fetchAll();
```

This is very complicated to implement within a class method. As you can see, I call the `execute()` method but I don't even know in advance if the `WHERE` clause will be used !

And even worse : what if I will want to use, let's say, the `LIMIT x, y` clause later on ?

Which parameters should I ask for and how to treat them ? Should I simply require the parameters to be one query + multiple variables that will be passed to the `execute()` method ?

Are these types methods reasonable for what I want to do ? Maybe I should to a dedicated method for each MySQL query the application will perform, but this is quite complicated because it's a big database and a big application.

What do you guys think ?

Thanks in advance :P

Answer (score 3):

Your API looks pretty useless to me, because as I see it it's just a wrapper around PDO. What do you gain by wrapping PDO like that?

Instead it would probably make more sense to have your object actually representing things, e.g.:

```
namespace Project\Storage\Database;

class Farm
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function getAnimalsByType(string $animalType): AnimalCollection
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = :animal');
        $stmt->execute([
            'animal' => $animalType,
        ]);

        // alternatively use a factory to build this to prevent tight coupling
        return new AnimalCollection($stmt->fetchAll());
    }
}
```

On a side note: forget about MVC in PHP (it's not even possible). Just focus on the more important [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Ok so you're saying I should divide my `Database` class into more specialized classes ? I think I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I should to a dedicated method for each MySQL query the application will
>   perform, but this is quite complicated because it's a big database and
>   a big application.

Yes, this is an easy way to organize your database access.

But you should not put ALL of them in the same class. You should separate your classes by their domain.

```
class animalRepository {

    // ...

    public function getAnimalByName($animal){
        $query = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM farm WHERE animal = :animal');
        $query->execute(array(':animal' => $animal));

        $result_set = $query->fetchAll();
        // ...
    }

}
```

To make this communicate more clearly you could call those classes repositories, as they are storing the data for the specific domain.

Another common name would be mappers, because they are mapping the data to your objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I will do is that : I will create a "root" model. Every other model will extend it. For example, `class Farm extends BaseModel {}`

Comment: Hm, I would not set such things in stone. You should only extend classes if it really makes sense. For the example repository class it would make sense to extend a `BaseRepository` class, so it does not have to implement the constructor itself, so if your `BaseModel` fullfills that function, ok - BUT the name `BaseModel` is extremely vague and does not communicate its purpose, so you should choose another name.

Answer (score 1):

Very opinionated answer. Anyway:

PDO's Prepared Statements are a little more capable than being created and calling `execute` on them. How you would usually do this is by first building your query and then binding the values:

```
$querystring = 'SELECT * FROM farm';
$args = array();
if($animal != '') {
    $querystring .= 'WHERE animal = :animal';
    $args[':animal'] = $animal;
}

$query = $this->_db->prepare($querystring);
$result = $query->execute($args)
if($result !== false) {
    // fetch ...
} else {
    // error output / return val
}
```

This is the general idea. Depending on your input parameters you build a query. It will probably become more sophisticated than that, for example filling a `$where = array()` and then you add to the `$where[] = ...` your where conditions and in the end you just join them all together with sql `AND`:

```
$this->_db->prepare($querystring.
                    ( count($where) > 0      // the > 0 is redundant btw
                      ? 'WHERE '.implode('AND',$where)
                      : '' ) 
                   );
```

You might similar things with joined tables, select statements and the like. It can get very complex. It's probably wise to mix this approach with separating at sensible points with Philipp's answer/approach.

Comment: I might try that, it seems like a good idea. But for your first example, what I give parameters to the method that requires the `LIKE` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: like is not a clause. it's more like `WHERE fieldname LIKE sometext`